# How do i install MinGW G++ 9.2

Tags: c++, gcc, installation, g++, mingw

When i install mingw, the old versions have the normal setup.exe file, but the g++ 9.2 that supports C++20 does not have setup.exe, it installs an archive instead, and that achive does not have any exe files, why is that happening, and how do i set it up ? and if there is any link to setup g++ 9.2 without the archive thing
i dont know is it from edge browser or not, and even the archive file does not install in downloads file, it is being installed in temp folder inside microsoft edge downloads and it is complex thing>

I didnt found any thing to try.

Comment: Why 9.2 when the current version is 12.x?  Or has 13 shipped? You install mingw via MSYS2. Any other method should be avoided.

Comment: If it doesn't have any exe files, perhaps the archive is not intended for Windows?

Comment: [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/#installation) has MinGW with gcc-13.1 and not such an old version you ask for.

Answer (score 0):

GCC 9 is quite old, current version of GCC is 13.

Also avoid old MinGW, use MinGW-w64 instead.

You can get recent GCC + MinGW-w64 for Windows in a number of ways:

- in [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) shell using its `pacman` package manager
- download a standalone build from https://winlibs.com/

Besides GCC there is also LLVM/Clang as an alternative. You can get it for Windows (also with MinGW-w64) here:

- https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw